# Collecting Docker events logs with Promtail

Tags: docker, logging, monitoring, grafana-loki, promtail

How can I get logs from docker events to Promtail?

I'm using Docker to run a set of containers on my server, and I would like to collect and centralize their logs using Promtail. Specifically, I would like to capture logs from the `docker events`(logs from the docker daemon about when the container is started, etc. ) command and send them to Promtail.

How can I achieve this? What are the steps and configurations I need to set up in order to get logs from docker events to Promtail?

Note that my Docker host is running on a Windows machine, and I'm using the latest version of Promtail.

my `promtail.yaml` file :

```
server:
  http_listen_port: 9080
  grpc_listen_port: 0

positions:
  filename: /tmp/positions.yaml

clients:
  - url: http://loki:3100/loki/api/v1/push

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: flog_scrape 
    docker_sd_configs:
      - host: unix:///var/run/docker.sock
        refresh_interval: 5s
        filters:
          - name: label
            values: ["logging=promtail"] 
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: ['__meta_docker_container_name']
        regex: '/(.*)'
        target_label: 'container'
      - source_labels: ['__meta_docker_container_log_stream']
        target_label: 'logstream'
      - source_labels: ['__meta_docker_container_label_logging_jobname']
        target_label: 'job'
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

add this job to your `scrape_configs:`

```
  - job_name: journal
    journal:
      json: false
      max_age: 12h
      path: /var/log/journal
      # matches: _syslog_identifier=dockerd
      labels:
        job: systemd-journal
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels:
          - __journal__systemd_unit
        target_label: systemd_unit
      - source_labels:
          - __journal__hostname
        target_label: hostname
      - source_labels:
          - __journal_syslog_identifier
        target_label: syslog_identifier
      - source_labels:
          - __journal__transport
        target_label: transport
```

This will collect all journal messages for all services. If you really want to only collect the docker service messages, you can uncomment the `matches` line.

I'm not sure what you'll need to change Windows specifically, but this works great on Ubuntu 22.04.